# automapper failing to set null value

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 classes which have a common CategoryId. One is the model for my Entity Framework object and the other is the MVC Viewmodel from where it is set.

What I have been trying to do it override the value of 0 and set it to null. Without doing this, I am getting Foreign Key errors and the specified User does not have a Category with id of 0.

I have define a map with the following, which to me reads as I want;

```
            cfg.CreateMap<EditListViewModel, List>()
               .ForMember(d => d.CategoryId,
                   o => o.MapFrom(s => s.CategoryId.Value == 0 ? (int?)null : s.CategoryId.Value));
```

So, the EditListViewModel will have a categoryId of 0, I want to to be null in the List.CategoryId

Comment: What error do you get? I don't see anything wrong with the code...

Comment: I only get the error when I do _dbContext.SaveChanges(); If I put a breakpoint on the object prior to sending to EF, I can see that the CategoryId is not being set from 0 to null.

Comment: Oh I see. I know this doesn't answer your question, but why do you have to make the id on the VM nullable? Is there a particular reason? Why not just do `cfg.CreateMap<EditListViewModel, List>().ForMember(d => d.CategoryId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.CategoryId);`

Comment: There is a constraint on the DB that the categoryID must exist for the user the List belongs to and ultimately, no user should have CategoryID of 0. Please note that Categories are optional, so will be null or > 0

Comment: @ChrisBint Do i understand it right that `List.CategoryId` is `0` instead of `null`? Did you tried `s.CategoryId.Value == 0 ? new Nullable<int>() : s.CategoryId.Value`?

Comment: @Rabban Yes. Changing to new int?() has no effect, it is still 0.